# Apache Reverse Proxy in Centos 7 by domains

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, centos7, virtualhost

I have an issue with my apache reverse proxy when I evoke domain dev.examle.com or examle.com from the backend server I always receive the same content. I don't receive content which specific virtual host. When I disable apache reverse proxy and backend serwer is main server, virtual host works as I want and shows content from path **/var/www/html/$domain/public_html/index.php**

On apache reverse proxy i have below configuration for domain.

**example.com**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName example.com
     ProxyPreserveHost on
     ProxyPass               / http://10.10.1.3/
     ProxyPassReverse        / http://10.10.1.3/
</VirtualHost>
```

**dev.example.com**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName dev.example.com
     ProxyPreserveHost on
     ProxyPass               / http://10.10.1.3/
     ProxyPassReverse        / http://10.10.1.3/
</VirtualHost>
```

It was my first problem because I can't find information how should I need update backend server? How enable to run ftp through apache reverse proxy ?

Comment: I have found solution of my first an issue. In backend server, virtual hosts have to run on another ports and these ports have to add in reverse proxy server for example http://10.10.1.3:8080